# Why am I getting a syntax error on this AppleScript to reload all tabs in Safari?

Tags: safari, tabs, applescript, reload

Getting an error on the following script which I copied to reload all tabs in a Safari session.

```
tell application "Safari"
    set a to tabs of the front window
    repeat with x in a
        set docUrl to URL of x
        set URL of x to docUrl
    end repeat
end tell
```

The error message is "Safari got an error: Can’t make missing value into type text."

The error appears to be on line "set URL of x to docUrl"

This is my 1st attempt at coding in AppleScript so please forgive any dumb mistakes.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that the `URL` property of tab return `missing value` although the tab shows valid data.

A more reliable way to reload all tabs is a JavaScript line

```
tell application "Safari"
    set allTabs to tabs of the front window
    repeat with aTab in allTabs
        tell aTab to do JavaScript "location.reload();"
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: Thanks Vadian - I will give this a try and report back. Appreciate your help.

Comment: It might be a good to point out that this requires that the Allow JavaScript from Apple Events menu item be checked on the Develop menu, of which the menu is hidden by default, in Safari.

Answer (score 0):

This will work if you have several windows with several tabs open.  This works for me using the latest version of macOS Mojave

```
tell application "Safari"
    set theTabs to every document
    repeat with eachTab in theTabs
        tell eachTab to set URL to (get URL)
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: Thanks for this - will try it